# How to determine which OpenGL engine is used in an Qt application: software or hardware?

Tags: qt, opengl

`glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` is working, but I need something like this:

```
qDebug() << isHardware(); // true or false
```

Because `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` may return different strings - it's quite hard to determine software or hardware automatically.

Comment: Which possible software renderers do you want to detect? If it's llvmpipe it's just a matter of asking for checking the `GL_RENDERER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @peppe wrote in a comment, the information can be found by calling `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` and looking for example for `llvmpipe`.